# What's the meaning of 'with' in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions

She can **run with** the best of them.

What's meaning of 'with' in the above context?

Comment: Have you looked in any dictionary for uses of the preposition 'with'? Was there anything you didn't understand?

Comment: -With -have many usage so i couldn't got it.

Comment: I like eggs with my toast. I saw my friend with his dog.

Comment: I sang with my friends in church.

Comment: *She can run **alongside** the best of them*  - she can keep up with the metaphorically fastest runners; she's ***as good as they are***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first meaning of 'with' (preposition) in Cambridge Dictionary is:

> with preposition
>
> used to say that people or things are in a place together **or are
> doing something together**

[With (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with)

If we say that someone can 'run with' the best of a group of people, we might mean literally that the group is running to some place, and the person can physically run fast enough among them to not be left behind, but more often we use the expression as a figure of speech to mean that the person can work, perform, or understand things, as well or as effectively as the best of the people in the group.